# Branch removal from history

Tags: git

I have this situation:

- The main branch is `Develop`
- I created a new branch from `Develop` called `Task1`
- I made changes in `Task1` and made a commit
- I made further changes in `Task1` and made another commit
- It turned out that the task should not be called `Task1` (for some reasons). A subtask called `Task2` had to be created
- `Task2` was created from `Task1` branch (in `Task2` needed changes were made in `Task1`)
- In `Task2`, I made further code changes

Now I would like to delete `Task1` branch from the history

Changes made in `Task1` must remain in `Task2`

Now is:

**Develop** - **Task1** : (commit1, commit2) - **Task2** : (commit1, commit2 etc.)

It should look like this:

**Develop** - **Task2** : (commit1, commit2, commit3 etc.)

EDIT:

`Task1` with commits must be removed but changes made remain in `Task2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 2):

A branch is just a pointer to a commit, so if `Task2` is ahead or at the same level of `Task1`, you can just delete `Task1`:

```
# delete the branch locally
git branch -d Task1
# delete the branch remotely (if you remote is not called origin, change that with your remote name)
git push origin :Task1
```

The commits accessible from `Task1` will still be in `Task2`.

Comment: This will only delete the local branch

Comment: Yes, there is no mentioned that the branch is pushed. I add this case though, in case.

Comment: Is it possible to move commits from `Task1` to `Task2`?

Comment: Run `git branch --contains lastCommitOfTask1`, if `Task2` is displayed you have nothing to do, every commits of `Task1` will be accessible from `Task2`, otherwise you can rebase or cherry-pick the missing commits in `Task2`.

Comment: Yes @DevNet read about [cherry picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). Please avoid asking multiple questions. Padwin has answered your question. If you want to ask more questions please use the ask a question button

Comment: Only that you change history would be useful to those commits

Comment: Can you rephase that please?